# ASP.NET MVC, Account Model : How to make relations to it?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I've created a new MVC 3 Internet Application, and it comes with the Account model/controller, etc.

Those are stored in a MDF database.

I'd like to create new models for my application, and make relations from these to my account model.

I did not find anything about it, maybe I looked for the wrong thing... So I was wondering, is there anybody who could point me in the right direction about how to do so?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using the standard ASP.NET membership provider? what do you use for your other DB operations?

Comment: Yes, I'm using the standard ASP.NET membership provider. As my database, I'm using SQL 2008 Express. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer I was looking for is exactly this:

In your model, link to the Membership User like this:

```
public virtual Guid UserGuid { get; set; }

public virtual MembershipUser User
{
    get
    {
        return Membership.GetUser(UserGuid);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Ah there in lies a problem with using the built in providers and aspnet default db.. In that database there is a unique id for each row - you in theory CAN use that to link to your databasse - but realize this is completely separate. One alternative many people do is to use a Custom Membership Provider (for example custom sql membership provider)
There are tons of articles/blogs out there on that - for starters see:
http://blogs.syrinx.com/blogs/dotnet/archive/2007/12/14/a-simple-custom-sql-membership-provider-part-1.aspx

This enables you to keep everything in your own database and its fairly easy to implement.

Answer (score 0):

I found this as well:
https://github.com/anderly/SimpleMembership.Mvc3

I guess it's another alternative.